# No member named 'tm' in global namespace when add React pod to my project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I met the No member named 'tm' in the global namespace issue when add the react pod to my project.

I searched so many ways, but most of them was show up because of the FFmpeg pod. I think maybe the problem is the same as https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect/issues/1, but I had remove all the Header Search Paths,but it didn't work.

Then, I think maybe the way to solve the FFmpeg is work for react, then I try to find if where the react use the time.h, but I didn't find. So I can't solve the problem as No member named 'clock' in the global namespace when using FFmpeg pod this is the Problem :
[Xcode alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wShN3.png)

I had delete all the header search paths.

I tried for 1 days, Is there anybody meet the same issue when add React Pod to the old project ? Any suggestion will be thankful!

Answer (score -1):

After check all pods in my project,I find the problem is not because React,it's all because FFmpeg.I had add the FFmpeg before react,but the React seems use the system time.h,but FFmpeg made it can't find the system time.h.Then I find FFmpeg don't use time.h at all ,so one solution is delete the time.h in FFmpeg,second way is rename the time.h in FFmpeg.But I know they are not the best way ,so I try to not add the .h files and add the header search paths,but it didn't work.Here is my settings,Any one can tell me why?
In Header Search Paths add 
 `"${PODS_ROOT}/../../../MyPod/FFmpeg-iOS/include"`

In MyPod podspec add:

`s.subspec 'FFmpeg-iOS' do |ss|
    ss.ios.vendored_library = 'CHiQTakeAwaySubApp/FFmpeg-iOS/lib/*.a'
end`

[Pod contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILv0.png)